# FFT filter vs lfilter in python

Tags: python, filter, fft

I have some troubles when applying bandpass filter to signal in Python. Have tried the following to things:

- Do the box window "by hand", i.e. do the FFT on the signal, apply the
  filter with a box window and the do the IFFT to get back to the time
  domain.
- Use the scipy.signal module where I use firwin2 to construct the
  filter and then lfilter to to the filtering.

Futhermore I have done the same filtering in the audio program Cool Edit and compared the result from the above two tests.

As can be seen (I am a new user so I can not post my png fig), the results from the FFT and scipy.signal are very different. When compare to the result from Cool edit, the FFT is close, however not identical. Code as below:

```
# imports 
from pylab import *
import os
import scipy.signal as signal

# load data 
tr=loadtxt('tr6516.txt',skiprows=1)

sr = 500            # [samples/s]
nf = sr/2.0         # Nyquist frequence
W = 512            # Window widht for filtering
N=float(8192)       # Fourier settings
Ns = len(tr[:,0])   # Total number of samples

# Create inpulse responce from the filter
fv=12.25
w    =0.5
r    =0.5*w
Hz=[0, fv-w-r, fv-w, fv+w, fv+w+r, nf]
ff=[0, 0,      1,    1,    0,      0]
b = signal.firwin2(W,Hz,ff,nfreqs=N+1,nyq=nf)
SigFilter = signal.lfilter(b, 1, tr[:,1])

# Fourier transform
X1 = fft(tr[:,1],n=int(N))
X1 = fftshift(X1)
F1 = arange(-N/2.0,N/2.0)/N*sr

# Filter data
ff=[0,1,1,0]
fv=12.25
w    =0.5
r    =0.5*w
Hz=[fv-w-r,fv-w,fv+w,fv+w+r]
k1=interp(-F1,Hz,ff)+interp(F1,Hz,ff)
X1_f=X1*k1
X1_f=ifftshift(X1_f)
x1_f=ifft(X1_f,n=int(N))
```

Can anyone explain to me why this difference? The filtering in Cool edit has been done using the same settings as in scipy.signal (hanning window, window width 512). Or have I got this all totaly wrong.

Best regards,
Anders

Above code:

[image]

Compared with Cool Edit:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could post your png on some free images hosting, like imgur, and provide a link.

Answer (score 0):

Small differences can be explained by the libraries using different algorithms that accumulate error slightly differently.

For example, if you compute the DFT using a radix-2 FFT, a split-radix FFT and an ordinary DFT, the results will all be slightly different. In fact the ordinary DFT has worse accuracy than all decent implementations of an FFT because it uses many more floating point operations, and thus it accumulates more error.

Could this explain the close (but not identical) results you are seeing?

Comment: the overall result is similar, but the amplitudes (on the filtered signal) are not totally synced. For instance, the max amplitude occur on different positions. For some reason I can not include figures, can I send one in some other way?

Comment: As @9000 mentioned above, its probably easiest to upload an image to imgur.com, and post the link in a comment

Comment: The above code generates the following results: http://imgur.com/CUH8j. As ca be seen, the result from the FFT and lfilter are not even close. When comparing to CoolEdit, the FFT is close, however differences exitst (http://imgur.com/YhbQN and http://imgur.com/H69nR)

Comment: Do you have some way of verifying the filter? If the CoolEdit filter works as expected, then I don't think you need to worry about the small amount of error between CoolEdit and the script above.

Comment: OK, That sound good. However, why such a big difference when using lfilter? In my opinion, there must be something fundamentally wrong with the way I use this filter.